# Creating an nxm matrix in Qml

Tags: html, canvas, matrix, qml

Right now i am trying to implement an **N**x**m** matrix in Qml. The only documentation I have found so far is for the **Matrix4x4** Qml type, and a 2 dimensional transformation matrix type. What is the easiest method for constructing arbitrarily sized matrices in this language? I should add that I have no experience in C++ at the moment so I would like to accomplish the matrix creation solely in Qml without the use of C++ files if possible. I understand there is a **QGenericMatrix** class but how is this implemented in QtCreator? Thank you!

Comment: You can create a JS array having length 16 as a data member and that's all. I can't see an even easier way.

Comment: Sorry, I might be misunderstanding, but I don't want to implement at 4x4 matrix (16 length). I want to implement a matrix with arbitrary size

Comment: You can still use a JS array. Use something like `var arr = [];` and fill it with whatever you want. If you put there `N*N` elements, you have a `N*N` matrix. Why not?

Comment: @skypjack I suppose that will have to suffice. Thank you

Comment: I'm adding an answer so as to accept it and close the question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can use a javascript array.
Something like `var arr = [];` should suffice.
Then you can fill it with whatever you want: if you put there `N*N` elements, you have a `N*N` matrix.